# bash associative array value empty using variable key, based on lookup file

Tags: bash, file, lookup, associative-array, rhel

I need to lookup data from a lookup file. I am using bash ver 4.1.2 on rhel.

Lookup data (ip_lookup.txt)

```
1.1.1.1=server A
2.2.2.2=server B
.. and so on
```

I iterate list from a file (aggregated from access.log) and need to add information from the lookup file.
iterated list (service.txt)

```
1234 service_a
324 service_b
34 service_c
```

access.log with x_http_forwarder info

```
service_a 200 1.1.1.1
service_a 200 1.1.1.1
service_a 200 2.2.2.2
service_b 200 1.1.1.1
service_c 200 2.2.2.2
```

So the code I made was this:

```
# import lookup file into bash array
declare -A ary
while IFS== read -r key value; do
    ary[$key]=$value
done < "ip_lookup.txt"

# then I nested iterate from list service and access.log
# list service and its caller
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line
do
        echo -e "${line[0]}\t${line[1]}"
        cat "access.log" | 
                tr -d \" | 
                sed "s/?wsdl.$PARTITION_COLUMN.\t/\t/g" | 
                sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' | 
                sed "s/?WSDL.$PARTITION_COLUMN.\t/\t/g" | 
                grep ${line[1]} | 
                awk '{ seen[$3] += $1 } END { for (i in seen) print seen[i],i }' | 
                sort -nr | 
                sed 's/ /\t/g' | 
                head -n 2 > "ip_list.txt"

        while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line
        do
                # the problem lie in this block <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                echo -e "> ${line[1]} \t\t ${line[0]} \t\t ${ary[${line[1]}]}"
                # it only returns var line 1 and line 0. While lookup var ${ary[${line[1]}] is empty
                # fyi, ${line[1]} returns 1.1.1.1 or 2.2.2.2 (on each iteration)
        fi
        done < "ip_list.txt"

done < "service.txt"
```

Let me highlight the problem:

```
ip=${line[1]}

echo $ip #it returns IP such as 1.1.1.1
echo ${ary['1.1.1.1']} # it returns server A

# but if I call the key using variable, it won't work. I've tried some combination but it works nothing.
echo ${ary[$ip]} # it returns nothing
echo ${ary[${line[1]}]} # it returns nothing
echo ${ary[${!line[1]}]} # it returns nothing
```

Any idea how to return the value using the key variable in bash associative array?
feel free to ask the detail.

Comment: I suspect your input file has dos line endings. `the problem lie in this block <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                echo -e "` Please show the output of your program. `cat "access.log" | tr -d \" | se...` that's a super long line - add newlines after every `|` to make it readable.

Comment: it return aggregated IP and count (ip_list.txt)

1234 service_a
324 service_b
34 service_c. what is dos line endings? there are no new lines after the last row of ip_list.txt. Also it returns fine if it's only to echo the file. ip=${line[1]};
echo $ip #it returns IP such as 1.1.1.1

Comment: "there are no new lines after the last row of ip_list.txt" That's a problem for a while-read loop. `read` returns non-zero if the line has no newline, which ends the while loop. Use `while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line || [[ -n ${line[0]} ]]; do` -- However, I don't understand how you get a file with no ending newline from redirecting the output of a pipeline.

Comment: To inspect the contents of a variable use `declare -p varname` -- works well with arrays too

Comment: ok i'll try check it, later. i'll update asap